# Console log returning empty value when calling for input field variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Why is console.log returning an empty line when calling for a text input's variable.

**HTML**

```
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="ticket-subject" />
```

**Javascript**

I tried the actual form and its `console.log` worked perfectly on submit, but somehow the value for `ticketSubject` seems to be empty.

```
const ticketForm = document.querySelector('.ticket-form')
const ticketSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;

ticketForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(ticketSubject)
    console.log('The form submit works')
})
```

Here's the subject field:

[image]

But it returns nothing:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. It makes total sense now and I got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the value of the input immediately when the page first loads, before the user has had a chance to enter a value.  Read the value in the `submit` event handler instead:

```js
const ticketForm = document.querySelector('.ticket-form')

ticketForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault()

    // read the value here
    const ticketSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;

    console.log(ticketSubject)
    console.log('The form submit works')
})
```

```html
<form class="ticket-form">
  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="ticket-subject" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the value inside the `addEventListener()` handler, otherwise the value is stored before the event and will never show up on the `console.log()`

```js
const ticketForm = document.querySelector('.ticket-form')


ticketForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(document.getElementById('subject').value);
  console.log('The form submit works')
})
```

```html
<form class="ticket-form">
  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="ticket-subject" />
  <button type="submit"> submit</button>
</form>
```